# Apply current selection as a layer mask to the current layer

Tags: applescript, photoshop

I have saved a selection as a channel called "circle".
I want to apply this selection as a layer mask to all layers

This is the script I have so far

```
tell application "Adobe Photoshop CC 2015.5"
   activate
   set theDOC to the current document

   tell theDOC
       set totalLayers to count each layer
       repeat with indice from 1 to totalLayers by 1

           tell layer indice

               -- load the channel
               tell theDOC
                   load selection of it from channel "circle" of it
               end tell

               -- I now need a magic command to apply the "circle"  selection that is active now, to the current layer as a layer mask, inside this loop

           end tell

       end repeat

   end tell

end tell
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a deep research I conclude that there is no way to do that, thanks to Adobe. The solution I have for this is:

1. create an action on Photoshop to add the selection as a mask.
2. call that action inside the loop using

   do action "mask" from "Default Actions"

   - change `mask` and `Default Actions` with your action name and set where the action is stored.

Enjoy.